# Timeago plugin not working in javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timeago

I have an `<abbr>` tag which has the class as `details italic` and the `title` property is set as the recent time with time stamp as `2011-02-08 10:42:04`. How am i suppose to call the timeago plugin in order to get the value as `2 hours ago` ?

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions](http://timeago.yarp.com/) are pretty particular on the timestamp format, it needs to be in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Just `2011-02-08 10:42:04` probably won't do.

Comment: `2011-02-08 10:42:04` does work fine for me. At least when using it like this `$.timeago('2011-02-08 10:42:04')`.

Comment: The timestamp changes for each row that will be added in my table. Will that matter in any way?

Comment: @Amol You mean the timestamp *format*? I don't know. Have you tried ISO 8601? Does it work? If not we need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [documentation](http://timeago.yarp.com/) does explain this pretty well. Did you try it and couldn't get it working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("abbr.details.italic").timeago();
});
```

Will call `timeago` on all `abbr` elements (with classes `details italic`) and change their value according to the date set in the `title` attribute.

Comment: I know that and i tried that but its still not working. I also tried mentioning jQuery instead of $

Comment: I am also having trouble using this outside of an html element by accessing it with $ or jQuery.